# Switch between UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have one UIScrollView embedded in another UIScrollView.

I would like to switch from the first one to the other one when the user scroll to a certain offset.

Is there an equivalent of `[textfield becomefirstresponder]`, that I can use? instead of setting my `scrollview.scrollEnabled = NO` and then setting it back to YES.

Thanks

Comment: We need more detail. Your question is not clear. A couple of things.. Where is the textfield ? in which scroller ? Why do you need an equivalent ? Why do you do scrollEnabled and then reset it ? Once a child scroller scrolls completely or do not start scrolling, parent is scrollable.

Comment: ...and if you can avoid scrollview within scrollview, it's often a bad user experience and unnecessary.

Comment: How would you do if you have two elements that scroll and when the first element reach a certain height the second start scrolling without passing in the background of the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple answer to it.
I just switch from one scroll view to another by changing the index of the subview

```
[self.view insertSubview:self.scrollViewA atIndex:0];
```

or

```
[self.view insertSubview:self.scrollViewB atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

One strategy would be to detect when you want to switch scroll views, then animate one of them offscreen and the other one on. For example, `scrollViewA` is currently being used and `scrollViewB` is offScreen. When the time comes for you to switch `scrollViewB` onscreen and `scrollViewA` offscreen, use a `UIAnimation` combined with `scrollingEnabled`.

```
- (void)timeToSwitchScrollViews
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations: ^{
        self.scrollViewA.frame = CGRectMake(/* somewhere off screen */);
        self.scrollViewB.frame = CGRectMake(/* somewhere on  screen */);
    }
    completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
        /* wait untill last minute to turn of user interaction */
        self.scrollViewA.scrollingEnabled = NO;
    }      
}
```